# in .net 6 (LTS) getting a http error 500 when call an action by ajax at web server

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

i'm trying to send an object(C# DTO class) from cshtml to controller using ajax. it is well work in visual studio when i debug but when i deploy at windows hosting server. And call the action by button click to perform logic and get result then i getting error that provide url not found http code 500.

Here is Js Code

```
<script>
    function sendTocreate() {
        $("#loading").show();

        const BarcodeCreated = new FormData();
           BarcodeCreated.append("airlineCode", $("#airlineCode option:selected").val());
           BarcodeCreated.append("airlineName", $("#airlineName").val());
           BarcodeCreated.append("mawb", $("#mawb").val());
           BarcodeCreated.append("destination", $("#destination").val());
           BarcodeCreated.append("origin", $("#origin").val());
           BarcodeCreated.append("package", $("#package").val());
           BarcodeCreated.append("weight", $("#weight").val());
           BarcodeCreated.append("hawb", $("#hawb").val());
           BarcodeCreated.append("company", $("#company").val());
           BarcodeCreated.append("nosCopy", $("#nosCopy").val());
   

        $.ajax({



            type: 'POST',
            url: '/barcodeManager/barcodeCreat',
            data: BarcodeCreated,
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false, 
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loading").hide();


                console.log(data.result);

                           if (data.success) {
                               $("#loading").hide();
                               $("#partialViewContainer").load("/barcodeManager/PartialViewAction{data:JSON.stringify(data.result) });

                           }
                           else {
                               Swal.fire({
                                   title: 'Something Went Wrong With Server !!!',
                                   icon: 'warning'
                               }).then((result) => {
                                   window.location.reload();
                               })
                           }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $("#loading").hide();
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

c# .net core 6 code

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult barcodeCreat(BarcodeCreated BarcodeCreated ){


           string airline = BarcodeCreated.airlineName;

           // fetched 11 dto class property and perform multiple mechanism to create barcode and save in    sql database finally return a created barcode detail as json string to shaow at views.


return json(new{success=true,data=result});

}
```

Result should be return json result to send view to show Barcode picture with provide details

Comment: 500 means the server crashed. We can't guess why from this incomplete code. Add proper exception handling and logging to the server and inspect the errors.

Comment: If the code reads from the database, the connection string may be wrong, the server may not exist or the account may be invalid

Comment: code insert dto into database and it is inserting good at debugging in visual studio

Comment: And fails in production, for whatever reason. That could be a bad connection string, invalid values, missing lookups. Add error handling and log the error

Comment: its solved I'm using a library inside the method, which throwing a exception in production mode.